# Does OS X respect Windows Server 2012 AD DS Fine-Grained Password policies?

Tags: active-directory, ios

Trying to setup fine-grained password policies, but Mobile Accounts on OS X seem to be hitting the default domain policy versus the fine-grained policy applied to the users.

Does the OS X AD plug-in support the fine-grained policies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my testing and research, the answer is "no".

According to [Best Practices for Integrating OS X with Active Directory](http://training.apple.com/pdf/wp_integrating_active_directory_ml.pdf)

"Are subject to the organization’s domain password policies".

It doesn't reference anything more specifically than the domain password policy, which is the only object that my test clients seem to recognize.